# How to change float to int if it's mathematically int? 2.0 -> 2. 2.5 -> 2.5

Tags: python

For example

```
def asdf(x): 
    return (x / 2) 


asdf(4.0)
asdf(5.0)
```

The returned value of  `2.0` will be converted to `2` whereas `2.5` won't be converted to `2`.

Answer (score 5):

The float object has a method `float.is_integer` to determine whether it is an integer:

```
>>> 2.0.is_integer()
True
>>> 2.1.is_integer()
False
```

So if it returns true, you can convert it to an integer:

```
>>> def asdf(x):
...     res = x / 2
...     return int(res) if res.is_integer() else res
...
>>> asdf(4.0)
2
>>> asdf(5.0)
2.5
```